# How are custom kernel functions in Gaussian processes statistically justified?

Tags: bayesian, inference, gaussian-process

I am confused about one aspect of the use of Gaussian processes for Bayesian inference. I understand that it relies on the assumption that your train and test data points form a multivariate normal distribution where you define a prior mean and covariance for the distribution. What I don't understand is that I believed covariance had a strict statistical definition $\text{cov}(X, Y) = \mathbb{E}\left(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)^\top\right)$. How is it justified statistically to just use what seems like any old function we like? I am pretty new to this so would appreciate if anyone could direct me to good resources on the topic too.

Comment: Choosing a covariance function for a Gaussian process is analogous to choosing a variance for a normal distribution prior. Just as you can have a prior with any $\sigma^2$ you like, so you can have a Gaussian process with any covariance function (the only requirement is that it will be positive-definite)

Comment: So following this, is it accurate to say that choosing a covariance function when sampling random functions is analogous to choosing a variance scalar when sampling random  variables?

Answer (score 0):

In [Gaussian Process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502531/elementary-explanation-of-gaussian-processes), your task is to learn the *distribution over functions* $$f(\mathbf{x}) = [f(x_1), f(x_2), \dots, f(x_n)]'$$ This distribution is modeled by Gaussian Process $\mathcal{GP}\left(m(\mathbf{x}),\, k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}')\right)$ parametrized by the *mean function* and *covariance function*

$$\begin{align}
m(\mathbf{x}) &= E[f(\mathbf{x})] \\
k(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}') &= E\big[\big(f(\mathbf{x}) - m(\mathbf{x})\big)\big(f(\mathbf{x}') - m(\mathbf{x}')\big)\big]
\end{align}$$

So the covariance function is the function that tells us what would the covariance be. It's the same as saying, for example, that the [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation) $E[y|\mathbf{x}]$ is given by a function $g(\mathbf{x})$, where in linear regression it would be a linear function $g(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{\beta}$. It doesn't say that we are not taking the integral to calculate the expectation anymore, but that the integral has a solution given by $g(\mathbf{x})$. It also doesn't say that any conditional expectation is like this, but that *this particular* random variable has an expectation that takes such form.

Gaussian Process defines such a distribution that if using the regular definition of covariance you calculated the covariance of $f(\mathbf{x})$ it would take the form of the covariance function.

Comment: Thank you, could you elaborate on the last point a bit more?

Comment: @3orange1red you can define a family of right triangles with sides $a,b,c$ such that $b = 2a$, so $c = \sqrt{a^2 + 2a^2}$. In the same way, you can define a family of distributions that share some property, or where some parameter is a function of something else.